# Consuming a SOAP web service error (No marshaller registered. Check configuration of WebServiceTemplate)

Tags: spring, web-services, spring-boot, soap, wsdl

I've followed the Getting Started - Consuming a SOAP web service (https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-web-service/) to consume a specific web service and everything works well:

I've made the configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class PMConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller() {
        Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        // this package must match the package in the <generatePackage> specified in
        // pom.xml
        marshaller.setContextPath("com.inteligenciaweb.wsdl");
        return marshaller;
    }

    @Bean
    public ProcuraPMPorREClient procuraPMPorREClient(Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller) {
        ProcuraPMPorREClient client = new ProcuraPMPorREClient();
        client.setDefaultUri("http://tempuri.org/procuraPMPorRE");
        client.setMarshaller(marshaller);
        client.setUnmarshaller(marshaller);
        return client;
    }
```

}

Client:

```
public class ProcuraPMPorREClient extends WebServiceGatewaySupport {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ProcuraPMPorRE.class);


    public ProcuraPMPorREResponse getPMPorRE(Integer RE) {

        ProcuraPMPorRE request = new ProcuraPMPorRE();
        request.setPMRENum(RE);

        log.info("Requesting PM for " + RE);

        ProcuraPMPorREResponse response = (ProcuraPMPorREResponse) getWebServiceTemplate()
                .marshalSendAndReceive("http://webservices.externo.policiamilitar.sp.gov.br:8071/router/wsscpm/basic",
                        request,
                        new SoapActionCallback("http://tempuri.org/procuraPMPorRE"));

        return response;
    }

}
```

At the class Application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class InteligenciawebApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(InteligenciawebApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner lookup(ProcuraPMPorREClient pm) {
        return args -> {
            Integer re = 123456;        
            ProcuraPMPorREResponse response = pm.getPMPorRE(re); 
            System.err.println(response.getProcuraPMPorREResult().getNomeBancoPM());
        };
    }
}
```

When I start a application, the weservice calling works fine, so I can see the result at the console. I've tried to use the same logic to call this web service in other class, but isn't working. For instance, I've made a test at the Controller Class:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/soap", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String testeSoap() {
    ProcuraPMPorREClient pm = new ProcuraPMPorREClient();
    ProcuraPMPorREResponse response = pm.getPMPorRE(123456); 
    System.out.println(response.getProcuraPMPorREResult().getNomePM());
  return null;
}
```

In this case, the webservice doesn't work and the system show this error message: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No marshaller registered. Check configuration of WebServiceTemplate. I don't know why, but the webservice works in a specific place and doesn't work in the other. If someone knows what happen, I apreciate! Thanks!

Comment: Oh, thank you! I've changed the ProcuraPMPorREClient pm = new ProcuraPMPorREClient(); to a @Autowired ProcuraPMPorREClient pm and now its working! Thanks!

Comment: Facing the same issue here , could you check it please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50759580/spring-ws-no-marshaller-registered-caused-by-spring-ioc

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In this case I cant instanciate a new object in the Controller like i've done:

```
ProcuraPMPorREClient pm = new ProcuraPMPorREClient();
```

Instead of this, I need to create a @Autowired object, like this:

```
@Autowired ProcuraPMPorREClient pm;
```

After, I only call the same routines:

```
ProcuraPMPorREResponse response = pm.getPMPorRE(123456); 
System.out.println(response.getProcuraPMPorREResult().getNomePM());
```

This worked fine.

Comment: This was really useful to me @Murilo

Comment: I faced a similar issue. I too resolved it by adding the client as Autowired. However, I am still searching for a answer as why the main worked with @SpringBootApplication annotation and why didn't the controller initiated call didn't work?

Comment: I am facing the same problem, but I have a spring5 application(not spring-boot). I have the config class annotated with Configuration and injecting using Autowired in my Controller class. Any suggestion please