# SPRING-WS No marshaller registered. Caused by SPRING IOC

Tags: spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, spring-ws

I have a SOAP client service which works fine.
The SOAP headers and request are managed in a `SOAPConnector class`.

```
public class SOAPConnector extends WebServiceGatewaySupport {

    public Object callWebService(String url, Object request) {
        // CREDENTIALS and REQUEST SETTINGS...
        return getWebServiceTemplate().marshalSendAndReceive(url, request, new SetHeader(requestHeader));
    }
}
```

I'm receiving the requested Data once I call my (SoapConnector) service on the `main Class`.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringSoapSecurityDemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringSoapSecurityDemoApplication.class, args); 
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner lookup(SOAPConnector soapConnector) {
        return args -> {
            String hotelCode = "****";
            FutureBookingSummaryRequest request = new FutureBookingSummaryRequest();
            FetchBookingFilters additionalFilters = new FetchBookingFilters();
           // Some additionalFilters settings
            request.setAdditionalFilters(additionalFilters);
            FutureBookingSummaryResponse response = (FutureBookingSummaryResponse) soapConnector
                    .callWebService("MY WSDL URL", request);
            System.err.println(response.getHotelReservations());
        };
    }
}
```

**SO FAR IT WORKS FINE.**

Then I've tried to create a separate service for the previous request.
`BookingService.java`

```
public class BookingService extends WebServiceGatewaySupport {
    @Autowired
    SOAPConnector soapConnector;

    public String getReservations() {
        String hotelCode = "****";
        FutureBookingSummaryRequest request = new FutureBookingSummaryRequest();
        FetchBookingFilters additionalFilters = new FetchBookingFilters();
       // Some additionalFilters settings
        request.setAdditionalFilters(additionalFilters);
        FutureBookingSummaryResponse response = (FutureBookingSummaryResponse) soapConnector
                .callWebService("MY WSDL URL", request);
        System.err.println(response.getHotelReservations());
    };}
```

In order to inject the SOAPCONNECTOR I've added `@Service` to SOAPCONNECTOR class , and `@Autowired` SOAPConnector soapConnector to the service calling it
Now once I call the created `BookingService` in the main class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringSoapSecurityDemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringSoapSecurityDemoApplication.class, args);
        BookingService bookingService = new BookingService();
        bookingService.getReservations();
    } 
}
```

The SOAPCONNECTOR stops working an I receive the following error :

> No marshaller registered. Check configuration of WebServiceTemplate.

I'm pretty sure that's this issue is related to SPRING IOC , dependecy injection .. Since the SOAP service is well configured and working..

Note : I've checked this similiar question 
[Consuming a SOAP web service error (No marshaller registered. Check configuration of WebServiceTemplate)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47886140/consuming-a-soap-web-service-error-no-marshaller-registered-check-configuratio?rq=1) but the `@Autowired` didn't solve the issue.
Any help ?

Comment: The problem is that your `BookingService` is extending `WebServiceGatewaySupport`.

Comment: Same issue after removing the extending !  According to the trace he problem is related to the SOAPConnector  ( at com.example.SpringSoapSecurityDemo.SOAPConnector.callWebService(SOAPConnector.java:59) )

Comment: You are also creating a new instance yourself instead of using the spring managed  instance.

Comment: @M.Deinum could you explain please ?

Comment: `BookingService bookingService = new BookingService();` don't do that. Use the spring managed one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case someone is facing the same issue, it turned out that I've missed the @Configuration annotation on the beans configuration class. The right one should look like the following:

```
    @Configuration
public class ConsumerConfig {

    private String ContextPath = "somePackage";
    private String DefaultUri = "someWsdlURI";

    @Bean
    public Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller() {
        Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        // this package must match the package in the <generatePackage> specified in
        // pom.xml
        marshaller.setContextPath(ContextPath);
        return marshaller;
    }

    @Bean
    public SOAPConnector checkFutureBookingSummary(Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller) {
        SOAPConnector client = new SOAPConnector();
        client.setDefaultUri(DefaultUri);
        client.setMarshaller(marshaller);
        client.setUnmarshaller(marshaller);
        return client;
    }
```

Comment: I am facing the same problem, but I have a spring5 application(not spring-boot). I have the config class annotated with Configuration and injecting using Autowired in my Controller class. Any suggestion please.